# existing web app, want to add 'Areas', what are the ramifications of this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an exising asp.net MVC app, and I want to add 'Areas' now.

What are the ramifications of this?
Any gotchas?

Comment: Is your existing app ASP.NET MVC 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

- Check your routes registration in
  Global.asax
- Check that you don't have
  hard coded link (without Html.Action
  or Ajax.Action) pointing to the controllers or action that you have moved to a new area

Answer (score 0):

If you add Areas then all of your routing will be different. Be sure to test all of your routes. Things might get especially hairy if you are going from one area to another - you will need to specify the area the routevalues (new {area = "myArea"}).

Comment: also, for the default route, make sure you specify a default area.

Comment: "add Areas then all of your routing will be different"  - This isn't true, existing routes can stay the same way they are now.

Comment: Also... If you want to get back to the 'root' area, set the area to `""`.